# ApplicationContextInitializer in a non-web Spring Context?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I've created an `ApplicationContextInitializer` implementation to load properties from a custome source (ZooKeeper) and add them to the `ApplicationContext`'s property sources list.

All the documentation I can find relates to Spring web-apps, but I want to use this in a standalone message-consuming application.

Is the right approach to instantiate my implementation, create the context, then pass the context to my implementation 'manually'? Or am I missing some automatic feature fo the framework that will apply my initializer to my context?

Answer (score 9):

I have found it simple enough to implement the SpringMVC's strategy for Initializing a context by initializing with a blank context.  In normal application contexts, there is nothing which uses an ApplicationContextInitializer, thus you must execute it on your own.

No problem, though since within a normal J2SE application given you have ownership of the context loader block, you will have access to every stage of the lifecycle.

```
// Create context, but dont initialize with configuration by calling 
// the empty constructor. Instead, initialize it with the Context Initializer.
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
MyAppContextInitializer initializer = new MyAppContextInitializer();
initializer.initialize( ctx );

// Now register with your standard context
ctx.register( com.my.classpath.StackOverflowConfiguration.class );
ctx.refresh()

// Get Beans as normal (e.g. Spring Batch)
JobLauncher launcher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can find the solution in Spring documentation *Section 4. The IoC container*

An example on how to start your app is here - [4.2.2 Instantiating a container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation)

Also have a look at [5.7 Application contexts and Resource paths](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other versions, but in Spring 4:

```
AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(yourConfig.class);
```