# Spring runtime app dependency by a Swing application, How to start the Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, swing, applicationcontext

I have 2 applications.

One is a swing application let's call it **SWING_ONE**, the other one is a JSE Spring enabled one with a Spring Context and it's used to communicate to webservices let's call is **SPRING_ONE**.

Now, I need **SWING_ONE** to start **SPRING_ONE** after it's done loading.

BUT !!!   **SPRING_ONE** is added via maven profile at runtime... so no `new appStart();` for me.

**SWING_ONE** has no Spring dependencies what so ever and cannot have them added.

I can mess around as much as I like with the **SPRING_ONE**.

this was being done by having **SWING_ONE** with this code

```
      String file = "jax-ws-embedded-context-" + Type + ".xml";
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
              new String[] {file});
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
```

But Spring was banned from it because there was no need to have it there, but now I cannot think of a way to have **SPRING_ONE**...

I created a `public void Main(String[args])` method inside the **SPRING_ONE** but **without using reflections  (I cannot use that too.)** I cannot think of a way to start it or make it's ApplicationContext auto load.

Thanks;

Comment: possible duplicate of [ApplicationContextInitializer in a non-web Spring Context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288841/applicationcontextinitializer-in-a-non-web-spring-context)

Comment: If you do not know the name of your app at compile time, you will have to use reflection to retrieve it at runtime.  FYI, Spring uses reflection all over the place to achieve its functionality, so the preevious solution of loading the Spring app context is effectively using reflection as well.  I would say that your problem is overconstrained.  There are some really horrible solutions, like autogenerating a .java file and then having Maven compile it, but I really think this is the sort of situation that reflection is intended for.

Comment: `Spring was banned from it because there was no need to have it there` - clearly there was...

Comment: I thought so too... but I lost the voting.